# Is it possible to setup global interceptor in WCF Data Service

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am currently using ChangeInterceptor to intercept changes to my entites. This is great and it allows me to do extensive logging.

```
[ChangeInterceptor("Products")]
public void OnChangeProducts(Product product, UpdateOperations operations)
...
```

I was wondering if there is a similar concept of interceptors in WCF so that I could measure the performance of the execution of a query. In brief (without using AOP), how can I intercept the begin and end of a call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are processing pipeline events. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474212.aspx.
You can register a handler for those events and they will fire at the beging and end of each request processing.